# Hibernate PersistentSet remove() operation not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, set, spring-data-jpa

I've a Set in my Parent entity as below:

```
Class Parent {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = parent, cascade = CasacadeType.ALL)
 Set<Child> children;
}

Class Child {
 @Column(nullable=false)
 @ManyToOne
 Parent parent;
}
```

Now event if I do a remove() operation on the Set for one of its element it doesn't actually get removed.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3799 says when the set is eagerly loaded Hibernate doesn't honor equals method. But here i'm using lazy loading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your mapping should look like this:

```
public class Parent { 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = parent, cascade = CasacadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
    
    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        children.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
    }
}

public class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Because you have a bidirectional association you have to have both sides in-sync.

Therefore, it's good practice to call:

```
parent.removeChild(child);
```

This way, `removeChild` is going to remove the `Child` from the `children` `Set` and also set the `Child` `parent` association to `null`.

Comment: i've updated the question. Parent object in Child can't be null.

Comment: The nullable=false is applied to the auto generated schema, if you use hbmddl. If you use the generated schema you may not set child.parent to null.

Comment: This does unfortunately not work, when the set is eagerly fetched: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3799 - only beginning with version 6

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem and although using remove and setParent to null, related data was at db still. After debugging I saw related child object couldn't been removed from parent's child list. When I searched "hibernate set remove not working" at net, I found the hibernate truth: remove method has some bug because hashcode and equals methods. After seing that I think maybe removeAll() method could work properly. I put related one object to list and put list to removeAll method and it succeeded. As an example:

```
List childList = new ArrayList();
childList.add(child);
parent.removeAll(childList);
child.setParent(null);
```

Comment: `parent.getChildren().removeIf(c -> c.getId() == child.getId())` should also work (tweaking if needed for a non-primitive ID, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause for such a failure might be:
A custom implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` which relies on properties that can change over time.
If such a property is modified *after* the object was added to the `HashSet`, it changes its hash and thus can no longer be found by `contains()` and `remove()`.

Consider the following example:

```java
public class Child {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Child(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    //other fields
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //instanceof checks for null, but whatever...
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Child)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.id == ((Child)obj).id;
    }
}
```

In the following snipped, the `HashSet` cannot remove the object because it cannot find it based on its new hash. Of course, it is not a bug, just one of the basic principles of a `HashSet` (which uses a `HashMap` internally).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child child1 = new Child(123);
    HashSet<Child> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    
    hashSet.add(child1); // puts to hash table at position X
    child1.setId(321);
    
    hashSet.remove(child1); // looks at position Y, finds nothing there
    //child1 is still in the set
}
```

PS: Note that this answer is not a perfect match for the question as asked
(the class in question does not override `hashCode` nor `equals`). It is more an explanation which depicts the most probable cause for the need of the 'workaround' mentioned by @Mustafa-Kemal AND you have to keep this in mind even when using the widely used approach mentioned by @Vlad-Mihalcea.

Note 1: `EntityManager::merge(...)` may change (and usually does) the memory-address of an object, used (not guaranteed for my part) for the default calculation of `hashCode()` - see `System.identityHashCode(Object x);` for more info.

Note 2: `EntityManager::persist(...)` may change the property used for hashCode calcullation IF you use a custom hashCode method - yes, I am talking about the primary-key, an id, here which is quite tempting to use as hashCode :)

Comment: Exactly this type of bug just took me half a day! The problem in a nutshell: Changing the properties used in your `hashCode()` implementation _after_ adding an Element to a `HashSet` makes it practically impossible to retrieve and thus to remove (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530061)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who looks for an up to date answer:

My Parent Entity was like:

```
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> childList= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And my Child Entity :

```
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I had the same issue and I could handle it when I created my own `delete()` method in my `Repository` like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Child c where c.id = :id")
void deleteById(Long id);
```

****using @Modifying is necessary**

And I called it from `Service` layer:

```
childRepository.deleteById(childInstance.getId());
```

Comment: What package is the modifying annotation from?

Comment: @Dragas Spring Data JPA