# Spring Data JPA - OneToMany child should be treated as a single resouce

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Data JPA 1.11.6.RELEASE, I have the following trouble;

With a simple 1-to-n relationship between them, I have `TableA`, and `TableB`, where `A` contains multiple `B`. And I have `RepoA`, that modifies not only `TableA`, but also `TableB` as a dependent child.

In this sense, when I have the following in DB (writing entities in JSON);

```
{
    "uuid": "f10cdd75-ffbe-49e6-b7a5-ad6f8e15b2b5",
    "name": "title",
    "listOfB": [{
        "pk": 1
    }, {
        "pk": 2
    }]
}
```

and I'd like to update `TableA`, and consequentially `TableB`'s with the following through `RepoA`;

```
{
    "uuid": "f10cdd75-ffbe-49e6-b7a5-ad6f8e15b2b5",
    "name": "title",
    "listOfB": [{
        "pk": 2
    }, {
        "pk": 3
    }]
}
```

But I am getting the constraint violation due to Hibernate following its famous order of operations, it tries to insert all dependent `TableB` values, without removing the original ones.

Is there no way to overwrite the `TableB` entities in any way? I was able to find this solution;

```
select `TableA` with `TableB` values
clear `"listOfB"`
save & flush `TableA` // deletes all current `TableB`
add new `B`'s to `"listOfB"`
save again
```

But it is very laborious, and ugly, plus the more such tables I have, the more such code I have to write. Can't I have some definition in `JPA` to allow this behaviour automatically? Do not treat this table as a proper table, but only as a basic resource, that should be overwritten in all update requests?

Comment: Post those entities.

Comment: @ChackoMathew as I said in my question, I've already posted them in JSON, please read before commenting...

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I was asking for the java entity classes for the tables.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125210/hibernate-persistentset-remove-operation-not-working or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363275/onetomany-delete-children should help