# @OneToMany delete children

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities like this :

```
public class Client {
  ...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE },orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private List<CompanyContract> companyContracts;
  ...
}
```

CompanyContract :

```
public class CompanyContract {

...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IDCLIENT")
private Client client;

...
}
```

And I want to delete a companyContract like this :

```
client.getCompanyContracts().remove(companyContract)
client = clientService.updateClient(client);
```

But the delete process is not happening

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

This is my updateClient method in my DAO :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Client updateClient(Client client) {

    return entityManager.merge(client);
}
```

Comment: Seems similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125210/hibernate-persistentset-remove-operation-not-working

Comment: You have to have both sides in-sync, set `CompanyContract.client` to null.

Comment: So what I need to do is remove CompanyContract from the list and then CompanyContract.client to null and Then update the Client ?

Comment: Yes, `orphanRemoval` will take care of deleting `CompanyContract` entry

Comment: I think `orphanRemoval` has nothing to do in this case. Becasue he want to delete one of `CompanyContract` in `Client` object. Not client and orphans from `CompanyContracts` neither `CompanyContract` and orphan `Client`

Comment: yes, I have a transaction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you don't need set `cascadeTypes` and `@Cascade`. I think it might be a source of your problems.

Did you `override`  `equals` and `hashCode` in `ContractCompany`? because maybe you are not removing the desired object from `List<ContactCompany>`

Look at this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", ...)
```

`mappedBy` informs hibernate that client is the *owner* of this relation, so you need to get `client`, get a list of `clientContracts`, remove one (make sure it's removed from the list), update client and object is removed.

Example source code below

```
CompanyContract toBeRemoved = //companyContract which you want to delete
client.getCompanyContracts().remove(toBeRemoved);
toBeRemoved.client = null;
```

save both objects, `toBeRemoved` and `client`

Comment: I already overrided Equals() and I overrided hashCode() now but it's the same thing, nothing happens

Comment: Are you sure that you removing object from the list? Did you tried to remove annotations responsible for cascades?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I checked the size of the list before and after the removal, And  Yes i've deleted the cascades as you mentionned (I left only the cascadeTypes and deleted @Cascade annotation )

Comment: Remove `cascadeTypes` too, if you omit cascade types argument they are set to all by default. You can also try to set `client` to `null` in `companyContract` which you want to delete. Then you also need to update `companyContract`

Comment: CompanyContract toBeRemoved = //companyContract which you want to delete
client.getCompanyContracts().remove(toBeRemoved);
toBeRemoved.client = null;
save both object, `toBeRemoved` and `client`

Comment: Add your last comment to your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Done I also added some more for future viewers :)

Comment: This is gold! I was struggling for three days - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cascade delete-orphan example
If you just want to delete two referenced ‘stockDailyRecords’ records? This is called orphan delete, see example…

```
1. No delete-orphan cascade
You need to delete the ‘stockDailyRecords’ one by one.

StockDailyRecord sdr1 = (StockDailyRecord)session.get(StockDailyRecord.class,
                                            new Integer(56));
StockDailyRecord sdr2 = (StockDailyRecord)session.get(StockDailyRecord.class,
                                            new Integer(57));

session.delete(sdr1);
session.delete(sdr2);
Output

Hibernate:
    delete from mkyong.stock_daily_record
    where DAILY_RECORD_ID=?
Hibernate:
    delete from mkyong.stock_daily_record
    where DAILY_RECORD_ID=?
```

2. With delete-orphan cascade
   The cascade=”delete-orphan” is declared in ‘stockDailyRecords’ to enable the delete orphan cascade effect. When you save or update the Stock, it will remove those ‘stockDailyRecords’ which already mark as removed.

   ```
   Stock stock = (Stock)session.get(Stock.class, new Integer(2));
   stock.getStockDailyRecords().remove(sdr1);
   stock.getStockDailyRecords().remove(sdr2);

   session.saveOrUpdate(stock);
   ```

   Output

   Hibernate:
       delete from mkyong.stock_daily_record
       where DAILY_RECORD_ID=?
   Hibernate:
       delete from mkyong.stock_daily_record
       where DAILY_RECORD_ID=?

In short, delete-orphan allow parent table to delete few records (delete orphan) in its child table.

You should be using cascade=”delete-orphan” in order to perform such a task.

[Reference](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

Comment: But I'm using `orphanRemoval = true`, isn't it the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with these annotations:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<CompanyContract> companyContracts;
```

Comment: Same thing, the deletion process is not occuring

Comment: try by removing @Fetch annotation